# Batch Script for get size of the text file

Tags: batch-file

I need my output to read as text file.
Here is the three files.
(1) Currently I have as an input  file
(2) Currently I have as an output file
(3) Actually What I need as an out put

I have six .ptp files. It's from G code. I need to get size of the each file by line by line same as in number (3)
**As an example:**
   Size of "01.ptp" is 123290 bytes

```
//(1)
@ECHO OFF

set "filename=*.ptp"
set "filename1=*_MachTime.txt"

for %%A in (%filename1%) do ( 
    for %%B in (%filename%) do (
        echo Size of "%%B" is %%~zB bytes >>shop1.txt
        )  
type %%A >>shop1.txt
)

exit​




//(2)

Size of "01.ptp" is 123290 bytes 
Size of "02.ptp" is 7714 bytes 
Size of "03.ptp" is 43473 bytes 
Size of "04.ptp" is 41137 bytes 
Size of "05.ptp" is 45802 bytes 
Size of "06.ptp" is 75346 bytes 

=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG01                                                        Time  26.92 MIN.
O0010         ToolD5_FLAT               S 3000.00  F 300.00                   Z -64.00  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Size of "01.ptp" is 123290 bytes 
Size of "02.ptp" is 7714 bytes 
Size of "03.ptp" is 43473 bytes 
Size of "04.ptp" is 41137 bytes 
Size of "05.ptp" is 45802 bytes 
Size of "06.ptp" is 75346 bytes 

=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG02                                                        Time  2.59 MIN.
O0020         ToolD2X10_FLAT            S 7500.00  F 200.00                   Z -57.20  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Size of "01.ptp" is 123290 bytes 
Size of "02.ptp" is 7714 bytes 
Size of "03.ptp" is 43473 bytes 
Size of "04.ptp" is 41137 bytes 
Size of "05.ptp" is 45802 bytes 
Size of "06.ptp" is 75346 bytes 

=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG03                                                        Time  8.30 MIN.
O0030         ToolD1X4_FLAT             S 7500.00  F 100.00                   Z -56.00  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Size of "01.ptp" is 123290 bytes 
Size of "02.ptp" is 7714 bytes 
Size of "03.ptp" is 43473 bytes 
Size of "04.ptp" is 41137 bytes 
Size of "05.ptp" is 45802 bytes 
Size of "06.ptp" is 75346 bytes 

=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG04                                                        Time  8.03 MIN.
O0040         ToolD1X4_FLAT             S 7500.00  F 100.00                   Z -56.00  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Size of "01.ptp" is 123290 bytes 
Size of "02.ptp" is 7714 bytes 
Size of "03.ptp" is 43473 bytes 
Size of "04.ptp" is 41137 bytes 
Size of "05.ptp" is 45802 bytes 
Size of "06.ptp" is 75346 bytes 

=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG05                                                        Time  7.10 MIN.
O0050         ToolD1_BALL               S 7500.00  F 200.00                   Z -50.27  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Size of "01.ptp" is 123290 bytes 
Size of "02.ptp" is 7714 bytes 
Size of "03.ptp" is 43473 bytes 
Size of "04.ptp" is 41137 bytes 
Size of "05.ptp" is 45802 bytes 
Size of "06.ptp" is 75346 bytes 
​



//////(3)
Size of "01.ptp" is 123290 bytes 
=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG01                                                        Time  26.92 MIN.
O0010         ToolD5_FLAT               S 3000.00  F 300.00                   Z -64.00  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Size of "02.ptp" is 7714 bytes 
=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG02                                                        Time  2.59 MIN.
O0020         ToolD2X10_FLAT            S 7500.00  F 200.00                   Z -57.20  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Size of "03.ptp" is 43473 bytes 
===================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG03                                                        Time  8.30 MIN.
O0030         ToolD1X4_FLAT             S 7500.00  F 100.00                   Z -56.00  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Size of "04.ptp" is 41137 bytes 
=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG04                                                        Time  8.03 MIN.
O0040         ToolD1X4_FLAT             S 7500.00  F 100.00                   Z -56.00  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Size of "05.ptp" is 45802 bytes
=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG05                                                        Time  7.10 MIN.
O0050         ToolD1_BALL               S 7500.00  F 200.00                   Z -50.27  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Size of "06.ptp" is 75346 bytes 
=======================================================================================
LAB12JT01-UG06                                                        Time  8.69 MIN.
O0060         ToolD0.6_FLAT             S 7500.00  F 100.00                   Z -51.60  mm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
​
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript` and `java`?

Comment: I  am ok with answers from Java and Java script also

Comment: Please reformat your question! Take a look at it -- isn't it chaotic??

Comment: What's the problem???

Comment: I need to get out put same as in (3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a global counter (`COUNTER`) and a local counter (`COUNTER2`). Print the size only if both counters match.

```
@ECHO OFF

set "filename=*.ptp"
set "filename1=*_MachTime.txt"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set COUNTER=0

for %%A in (%filename1%) do (
    set COUNTER2=0

    for %%B in (%filename%) do (
        rem if !COUNTER2!==!COUNTER! echo Size of "%%B" is %%~zB bytes >> shop1.txt
        rem update with size in KB
        set /A KBS=%%~zB/1024
        if !COUNTER2!==!COUNTER! echo Size of "%%B" is !KBS! bytes >> shop1.txt
        set /A COUNTER2=!COUNTER2!+1
        )
    set /A COUNTER=!COUNTER!+1
type %%A >> shop1.txt
)
```

Not very elegant but hey, it's batch files after all what do you expect ?

Comment: Can somebody help me to get out put by Kilobytes in above example?Only need change byte value to kilobyte

Comment: `set /A KB=%%~zB / 1024`. Untested maybe would need !KB! instead of %KB% for printing inside the loop

Comment: please see my updated coding ne, I think you can help me, I can't get rounding value. thanks

Comment: I have original time files from 01.MathTime.ptp format. But I need to convert .ptp to .txt by coding in above program? If please help

Comment: I have updated the answer for size in kb. But I don't understand your last .ptp to .txt question. If it's a different question, maybe ask another one. Or edit your question. Many changes have been introduced since the original question. It degrades reading value for others.

Comment: It's same question, that's why I mention like this. I have two format of files in this program. ptp and txt .original "filename1" are ptp files. So I need to convert these files to txt format before execute the program. I want to do this one as a code? Example :ren *.(current extension name) *.(extension you want)

Comment: yes, `ren *.ptp *.txt` would work. It's the only command that made me think that MSDOS was superior to unix. Well, really the only one :)